# .Net MVC 3 with Ninject and the [Inject] attribute configuration

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

i replaced the **HttpAplication** inheritance in my **Global.asax** to **NinjectHttpApplication**:

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return Bootstrapper.CreateKernel();
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(CreateKernel()));
        Bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
    }
}
```

And my CreateKernel method:

```
public static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    return kernel;
}
```

I need to use the **[Inject]** attribute in my RoleService that use RoleProvider and is started by asp.net.

All say that if I inherit from **NinjectHttpApplication** in my **Global.asax** I don't need that line: `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));` in my **OnApplicationStarted** method, but without that a exception is thrown and my dependency is **NULL** in my RoleProvider Service.

After all, I need that line or not? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The DependencyResolver is set by the extension during startup. If the service is created before ApplicationStart then the default one will be used. From your code I cant tell when it gets created. But normally this line shouldn't be required.

You can also try to use the NuGet way to integrate Ninject. This will start the Ninject Kernel and DependencyResolver a bit earlier.

Comment: what's the NuGet way?

I noticed a new behavior in my app: with this line "DependencyResolver.SetResolver(...)" in my OnApplicationStarted() method, the RoleService is not triggered by asp.net, why?

Comment: You didn't provide any information about your role service and how it is started. So I can't help you with that. About NuGet: Download the NuGetPackage and everything will be setup . Also read: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

Comment: I did download from TeamCity of DLL: Ninject, Ninject.Web.Common and Ninject.Web.MVC versions 2.2.3. The NinjectHttpApplication class don't exist anymore? My problem was resolved using kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);